# How to make a property dependent on the keys of a record of another property in the same interface?

Tags: typescript

I would like to make `bar` allow only keys of the `foo` record.

Below my attempt that does not work.

```
interface Test {
    bar: Record<string, string>;
    foo: (keyof Test["bar"])[];
}

const test: Test = {
    bar: { hello: "world" },
    foo: [
        "dummy", // should not work, but typescript does not emit error!
        "hello" // should work
    ]
};
```

Is it possible in typescript ? Generics can help but I'd rather not have to specify any type like `const t:Test<"hello"> = {...` for instance.

Comment: Generics are pretty much necessary for this.  When you say you don't want to specify, would a helper function be acceptable?  So instead of `const t: Test = {⋯}` you write `const t = test({⋯})`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDJZ8W)? If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach won't work because `keyof Test["bar"]` will evaluate to type `string` so foo's type will be `string[]` and therefore it becomes eligible to hold any kind of string, you'll have to specify at compile time what keys bar will hold otherwise typescript won't be able to infer it.
One way to avoid having to make the `Test` class generic is to do this:

```js
type BarKey = "hello" | "someKey";

interface Test {
    bar: Partial<Record<BarKey, string>>;
    foo: (keyof Test["bar"])[];
}

const test: Test = {
    bar: { hello: "world" },
    foo: [
        "dummy", // will complain now!
        "hello" // should work
    ]
};
```